# Vim — replace ‘foo’ by ‘bar’ on lines NOT starting with ‘character’

Tags: regex, vim, replace

In Vim regular expression, I know it is possible to replace `foo` by `bar` on all lines starting with `%` using

```
:g/^%/s/foo/bar/g
```

but I want to replace `foo` by `bar` on all lines NOT starting with `%`. Is there a way to easily do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just negate the `%` character using `character class`: -

```
:g/^[^%]/s/foo/bar/g
```

`[^%]` match any character except `%`, at the start of the string.

Answer (score 11):

Try `:vglobal`:

```
:v/^%/s/foo/bar/g
```

Answer (score 6):

The inverse of `:g` is `:g!`, so your example could be expressed:

```
:g!/^%/s/foo/bar/g
```

Note that `:g!` is just another way of writing `:v` (cf. Jim Davis' answer)

Answer (score 3):

try `:g/^[^%]/s/foo/bar/g` to match all lines not starting with %